# Page layout gets messed up in different computers, auto-adjustment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably has a really easy solution, since it is one of the most basic things in web design.

After a lot research and not finding the answer decided to ask it. Basically my webpage looks        perfectly fine on my 13" Macbook but all the elements get messed up when I try to display it on my 27" desktop. I understand the core of the problem is that, when I set something to 300px, it covers much of the screen in 13" but just a little in 27" thus causing everything to sit on top of each other but I failed at finding a solution. Just to be clear, this is not a 100% issue of responsiveness, I don't want different layouts for different screens but I just want the same layout to look ok in many screens, just like you are resizing the page from the corners. Here is some of the code that I hope will be helpful. Also things that I have tried:

1. Using em instead of px. Not really helpful.
2. Using % instead of px. Not really helpful in cases like the first jumbotron where parent element doesnt have a defined height

HTML :

```
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="images/banner.jpg" >
</div>

<div id="menu"> 
        <ul  class="nav nav-pills navbar-left">
            <li> <p> 1 </p></li>
            <li> <p> 2 </p> </li>
            <li> <p> 3 </p></li>
            <li> <p> 4 </p></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
            <li id="toleft"> <p> 5 </p> </li>
            <li> <p> 6  </p></li>
            <li> <p> 7 </p> </li>
            <li> <p> 8 </p> </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<!-- Script to fix navbar-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 450;
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                    $('#menu').addClass('fixed');
                }
                else {
                    $('#menu').removeClass('fixed');
                 }
            });
    });
</script>

<div id="displayframe">
    <div id="display">
        <img id="mainimage" src="images/col1.jpg" height="420" width="960" />
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Script for changing images with time-->
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var imageArray = ["images/col2.jpg", "images/col3.jpg", "images/col4.jpg", "images/col5.jpg", "images/ban.jpg"];
        var count = 0;

            function loadImage(){
                $("#mainimage").attr("src", imageArray[count]);

                    if(count == imageArray.length){
                        count = 0;
                    }else{
                        count = count + 1;
                    }   
            }
            setInterval(function(){
                loadImage(); 
            }, 3000);
    })
</script>

<div class="container">
        <div id="head">
            <p> RECENT NEWS </p>
        </div>
</div> 


<div class="newsfeed">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p style="float: left;"> <img src="images/chris.jpg" width="190px" /> </p>
            <h2></h2>
            <p id="bodypart">
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="newselement"><p style="float: left;"> <img src="images/city.jpg" width="190px" height="280px" /> </p>
            <h2></h2>
            <p id="bodypart">
            </p></li>
        <li class="newselement"><p style="float: left;"> <img src="images/alex.jpg" width="190px" height="280px" /> </p>
            <h2></h2>
            <p id="bodypart">
            </p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background-color: black !important;  
}

.jumbotron{
height: 320px;
background-color: black !important;  
}

.jumbotron > img{
width: 100%;
margin-top: -50px;

}

#toleft{
left: -10px;
position: relative;
}

.nav p{
font-family: "Crimson Text";
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-left{
margin-left: 20px;
position: relative;
}

.navbar-left li{
width: 120px;
}

.navbar-right{
left: -50px;
margin-left: 0px;
position: relative;
}

.navbar-right li{
width: 140px;
}


#menu{
background-color: black;
width: 99%;
margin-top: -110px;
}

.nav li p{
padding-left: 15px;
}

.fixed {
position: fixed; 
top: 110px; 
height: 50px; 
z-index: 1;
background-color: black;
}

#display{
width: 960px;
height: 420px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
margin-top: 130px !important;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: white;
} 

#display ul{
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:  960px;
width: 420px;
list-style: none;
}

#display ul li{
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 960px;
height: 420px;
}

#head > p{
font-family: "Crimson Text";
font-size: 30px; 
font-weight: bold;
}

#head{
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 85px;
}

.tweets{
background-color: rgba(247,12,12,0.3);
margin-top: -800px;
margin-right: 50px; 
border: 1px solid white;
border-color: white;
}

.newsfeed{
margin-left: 100px;
width: 60%;
height: 800px;
}

.newsfeed > ul{
list-style: none;
}

.newsfeed > img{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
float: left;
}


.newsfeed > h2{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: 50px;
float: right;
}

.newsfeed > li{
border-bottom: 1px white;
border-top: 1px white;
border-color: white;
height: 400px;
}

#bodypart{
font-size: 17px;
}

.newselement{
border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is `responsive issue` only because you are viewing your page on different screen or resolution. So if you want to create responsive website you have to add `@media queries` for different resolution.
-- `@media queries`
-- `Outer div` should keep fixed `(px)` or in percentage `(%)`.
-- And `inner div` or content should wrap according to outer div width eg(width:100%).
-- Finally depend on different resolution change your `css` in @media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Px (pixels) which are pre-fixed? Instead play around with % (percents) which allow you to scale your webpage based on the user's screen. You could make your image 1600px wide which would be the full length of your MBP but for example on your Imac it only shows your image 1600px wide when really the Imac has 2880px for the screens width. Therefore you have another 1280px remaining to fill. If you were to use 100% it would fill 100% of who's ever screen is viewing your webpage. Hope this some what helps. You lost me on the 300px off.

Comment: There is only one problem with that. when I set height of .jumbotron to be 40% it doesnt work... any ideas on that maybe ?

Comment: Is it not layering right? If there is an image or div that you want to see over the top of the other one try using the z-idex.

Comment: No that is not the problem :/
basically 
.jumbtron{
height: 40%
}
gives the same result as
.jumbtron{
height:90%;
}

Comment: make a jsfiddle with the code and images linked up so I can see it

Answer (score 0):

I have setup a [**JSfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mh3q3vxs/).

I found a few things that you could add/modify to help improve your code and get things aligning better.
`<img src="images/banner.jpg" >` was not closed correctly you missed the / `<img src="images/banner.jpg" />`. Also you have no clearing tags anywhere in your code so of course when the width of your page scales out the elements on the page are going to stack up beside each other. I created a class;

```
<div class="clear"/>
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

This i placed below each of your element sections so it will return them to the next line.

Next i placed a wrapper and a content div around your whole page content to center-align the content and make the page width 1000px (which is standard among most websites).

The images were not rendered into the JSfiddle becaise the paths are relative to your computer so i left them blank. If you want to see it working better please update the JSfiddle and i can help further.

-Epik